# JASON EN ARRAY EN JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, jsonarray

Tengo un array de objetos en js. De este tipo

```
let objUno = {
Traumatologia: [
  {
      HORA: "8:00",
      ESPECIALISTA: "MARIA PAZ ALTUZARRA",
      PACIENTE: "PAULA SANCHEZ",
      RUT: "15554774-5",
      PREVISION: "FONASA"
  },
  {
      HORA: "10:00",
      ESPECIALISTA: "RAUL ARAYA",
      PACIENTE: "ANGÉLICA NAVAS",
      RUT: "15444147-9",
      PREVISION: "ISAPRE"
  },
  {
      HORA: "10:30",
      ESPECIALISTA: "MARIA ARRIAGADA",
      PACIENTE: "ANA KLAPP",
      RUT: "17879423-9",
      PREVISION: "ISAPRE"
  },
  {
      HORA: "11:00",
      ESPECIALISTA: "ALEJANDRO BADILLA",
      PACIENTE: "FELIPE MARDONES",
      RUT: "1547423-6",
      PREVISION: "ISAPRE"
  },
  {
      HORA: "11:30",
      ESPECIALISTA: "CECILIA BUDNIK",
      PACIENTE: "DIEGO MARRE",
      RUT: "16554741-K",
      PREVISION: "FONASA"
  },
  {
      HORA: "12:00",
      ESPECIALISTA: "ARTURO CAVAGNARO",
      PACIENTE: "CECILIA MENDEZ",
      RUT: "9747535-8",
      PREVISION: "ISAPRE"
  },
  {
      HORA: "12:30",
      ESPECIALISTA: "ANDRES KANACRI",
      PACIENTE: "MARCIAL SUAZO",
      RUT: "11254785-5",
      PREVISION: "ISAPRE"
  }
],

}
```

Quiero introducir datos por medio del método push , del siguiente modo

```
Traumatologia.push({HORA:"09:00",ESPECIALISTA:"RENE POBLETE",PACIENTE:"ANA GELLONA",RUT:"13123329-7",PREVISION:"ISAPRE"},
{HORA:"09:30",ESPECIALISTA:"MARIA SOLAR",PACIENTE:"OSCAR ANDRADE",RUT:"12221451-K",PREVISION:FONASA},
{HORA:"10:00",ESPECIALISTA:"RAUL LOYOLA",PACIENTE:"RENATO ISLA",RUT:"10112348-3",PREVISION:ISAPRE},
{HORA:"10:30",ESPECIALISTA:"ANTONIA LARENAS",PACIENTE:"JUAN LOAYZA",RUT:"13453234-1 I",PREVISION:ISAPRE},
{HORA:"12:00",ESPECIALISTA:"MATÍAS ARAVENA",PACIENTE:"JUANITA POBLETE",RUT:"14345656-6",PREVISION:FONASA},)
```

Lamentablemente algo falla ¿qué se debe corregir? Esto lo pregunto porque aparece subrayado la zona donde escribo el método push . Además me rompe el esquema de la pagina web que poseo, en lugar de incorporarse a la tabla que recoge la información

Comment: Suponiendo que estes haciendo objUno.Traumatologia.push(), el error se encuentra en la ultima propiedad de los ultimos 4 objetos que tratas de introducir, donde FONASA y ISAPRE deberian ser strings y allí se ve que son variables

Comment: Excelente ayuda . Muchas gracias

Comment: si te sirvió puntua^-^